# Android Foreground service killed without warning/notification

Tags: android, delphi, foreground-service

I have an Android App with a ForeGround Service, which is started as 'Sticky'.
It is written in Delphi Pascal (11.1)

When I shut down my main App, including the Service (with a TAndroidHelper.Activity.stopService(LIntent)) then the Service gets a proper OnDestroy message, which allows it to save all data.

But, when the main App is killed by the OS, or when I kill it from the display myself, the ForeGround Service gets killed without any warning. It then is restarted a few seconds later by the OS because it is sticky.

Why does the Service not get any warning in this case before being killed?
Is there another notification system which I can install, which the OS send a notification to, so I can properly shutdown the Service?

Comment: Starting it as "Sticky" is not enough. I found that you have to literally call `StartForeground` with a massive hassle in delphi. There's a sample provided by embarcadero on how to achieve this. `ForegroundLocationTracking`

Comment: My Service it permanenly running as Foreground. This example switches the Service between background and foreground, every time the main App goes to the background. Hmm.  But this does not answer my actual question on the Servive not getting a warning before being killed.

Comment: If you add an `ApplicationEventHandler` to your host,  that handler will receive notifications when you app becomes 'Active', 'Inactive', 'Will terminate' etc. Then you can perform whatever actions you need to do with your service as you require.

Comment: Yes, I have one in my App main program. But the Service runs by itself. The events the App gets, should be independent of what happens to the Service. The App also gets 'Will Terminate' messages in cases where the Service is *not* about to be killed by the OS, and should then no do anything at all. Can I also add a ApplicationEventHandler to the Foregound Service?